# Science-fiction book: man sent off-planet by his father-in-law (a corporation boss), his kid sister-in-law gets involved in his music writing

Tags: story-identification, books

Several years ago I read a SF book about a young man engaged to a girl whose father ran a big corporation. Visiting the stronghold, the young man met the girl's kid sister and made friends with her.  The father sends him off-planet for several years, and when he finally sees them again in space, he doesn't like the older girl but the kid sister is grown up and he likes her.

Part of the story involves his writing music, and the kid sister getting involved in his music.

Comment: So, "several years ago" would be somewhere in the 2010 timeframe? Was this a paperback? Hardback? Story in an anthology? Do you remember anything about the cover art? When he returned, was he in his 20s? His 30s? Older? :) If you click on the `story-identification` tag, you'll see a section of rmore information that includes a list of questions you can answer to help us help you.

Comment: Also on the site concerning the same story: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24178/man-joins-the-military-while-drunk-and-goes-on-a-near-lightspeed-ship.

Answer (score 4):

*Variable Star* by Spider Robinson.

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_Star):

> *Variable Star* is a 2006 novel written by Spider Robinson based on the surviving seven pages of an eight-page 1955 novel outline by the late Robert A. Heinlein. The book is set in a divergent offshoot of Heinlein's Future History and contains many references to works by Heinlein and other authors. It describes the coming of age of a young musician who signs on to the crew of a starship as a way of escaping from a failed romance.

Comment: The summary at https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/50847.Variable_Star provides even more confirmatory information.